# Optimizing a function for either a pointer or a scalar

Tags: c++, templates

I have a complicated program that I am trying to optimize. After some testing I isolated a function that looks as follows:

```
void sum(int* res, int* a, int* b, int size){
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
       res[i] = a[i] * (b[i]+1);
    }
}
```

I frequently call this function with a repeated second or third argument, so I optimized it as follows

```
void sum(int* res, int* a, int b, int size){
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
       res[i] = a[i] * (b+1);
    }
}
```

or as follows

```
void sum(int* res, int a, int* b, int size){
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
       res[i] = a * (b[i]+1);
    }
}
```

Note that the second or third argument are either scalars or pointers. Is there a way to use C++ template magic to have all three versions without having to repeat the implementation?

DISCLAIMER: My function, which is too complicated to list here, is not as simple as the example. But if I know how to write the template for this simple example, I should be able to adapt the solution to my problem.

Comment: It's hard to say. Can you provide something that causes an error? From what you've shown here, which I know is not exactly the same, overloading should take care of things already.

Comment: You want to optimize for speed or for size?

Comment: Yes indeed. Overloading works perfectly. But I dislike the fact that I have to repeat the implementation three times. The real program is more complicated so repeating the implementation 3 times is quite the maintenance hassle.

Comment: @AndyG I think the idea is to share the implementation, not dispatch to one of the three versions.

Comment: @Adrian Maire, I want to optimise for speed. I don't particularly care about the size of the executable. But I don't want to have to maintain three, almost identical, versions of the function.

Comment: Overloading should be no issue. If there is a lot of repeated code, factor out the common bits so that the resulting functions are small. If we want to get fancy with templates we'll write some kind of `GetValue` function that gets specialized both for scalars and pointers, which is no different than the overloading I suggested.

Comment: To me, those 3 functions are different, and trying to use template magic will make this code harder to read and maintain, not easier. Joining those functions will definitively not optimize speed.

Comment: I'd focus more on optimising each of the functions separately.   The differences between them mean that trying to fold them into one will make it harder to optimise any of them (or mean that optimising one compromises performance of another).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is simply to make `sum` a template and factor out the difference between implementations, that is the array or scalar access:

```
namespace detail_arrayish {
    template <class T>
    auto &access(T &single, int) {
        return single;
    }

    template <class T>
    auto &access(T *array, int n) {
        return array[n];
    }
}

template <class A, class B>
void sum(int* res, A a, B b, int size) {
    using detail_arrayish::access;

    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
       res[i] = access(a, i) * (access(b, i) + 1);
    }
}
```

This should be completely optimized by any self-respecting compiler.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67411d7d6233d24a)

Comment: Great. I modified your solution a bit to always use indexers, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc77a6b89247afbb). I guess my code should also be optimized by modern compilers.

Comment: @Tohiko [it is](https://godbolt.org/g/pDR4wn)! Aren't modern compilers beautiful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is complex behaved, but your terms are relatively simple, you don't necessarily need templates, overloading the right factoring would be enough.

E.G.

```
void sum(int* res, int a, int b, int i){
    // your complex function here
    res[i] = a * (b+1);
}


void sum(int* res, int* a, int* b, int size){
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i){
       sum(res, a[i], b[i], i)
    }
}

void sum(int* res, int* a, int b, int size){
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i){
       sum(res, a[i], b, i)
    }
}

void sum(int* res, int a, int* b, int size){
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i){
       sum(res, a, b[i], i)
    }
}
```

The work can be all in one function while overloads only take care of indexing synchronously if/as needed.

On the optimization side, without seeing the function, it's hard to tell what would be going on.

Re: "optimizing for speed", assuming you know your algorithm is already in a good state and making good use of appropriate Cpu instructions, If you throw around pointers liberally with no constness and no-alias promises you are more likely to pay for that than for the layout of your functions and how they are called (which when indirected in such straight forward fashion the compiler will usually do a decent job of anyway regardless of templating or overloading).

If your types are literals/simple don't make the mistake of assuming that lobbing around as much as possible as pointers or references will help, it often won't (and some times will be deleterious). A core function taking the simple terms as value is likely to win in the long run.

This might or might not apply to your work, hard to tell when extrapolating from the simple example.

P.S.
I also replaced those `i++` with `++i` because they were bothering me to no end :)